# Jira Jenkins issue

Tags: jenkins, jira, jira-plugin

I have install JIRA plugin for jenkins, but not able to create JIRA when build fails.

Getting following error-

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at hudson.plugins.jira.JiraSession.createIssue(JiraSession.java:337)
 at hudson.plugins.jira.JiraCreateIssueNotifier.createJiraIssue(JiraCreateIssueNotifier.java:168)`hudson.plugins.jira.JiraCreateIssueNotifier.currentBuildResultFailure(JiraCreateIssueNotifier.java:355)` at hudson.plugins.jira.JiraCreateIssueNotifier.perform(JiraCreateIssueNotifier.java:133)`
```

I have properly inserted post build actions for create jira.
as well as authenticate user properly.

Comment: Either it's a bug in the plugin or your configuration in Jenkins/JIRA is missing something, but you'll have to provide all the details to figure that out.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It's probably a bug: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-38293